# Lighthouse is not working for react application

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, lighthouse

Chrome extension Lighthouse is not working for react application always returns 1 or 2 as the performance. I have disabled all the chrome extensions.

Not sure what I am missing - been stuck with it for the past week.

Please let me know what am I missing

Comment: are you running it with react running dev mode?

Comment: no created NPM run build and rendering the view with Nodejs

Comment: Did you analyze what the performance metrics are returning to you? For me Lighthouse has always worked with React apps.